# Как вывести звездный рейтинг в комментариях Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как в каждом комментарии вывести рейтинг, который выставил пользователь?

Comment: а как Вы делаете рейтинг для комментариев? в базовых полях комментария - нет рейтинга

Answer (score 0):

> Как в каждом комментарии вывести рейтинг, который выставил пользователь?

Чтобы что-то "вывести" это вначале нужно "завести". А рейтинга по умолчанию нет.

Поэтому его надо либо писать свой плагин либо воспользоваться готовым. И уже от этого будет зависеть "как вывести".